# Can PostgreSQL's COPY create CSV with Locale-specific number formatting?

Tags: postgresql, csv, bulkcopy

I want to create a CSV with PostgreSQL 9.1 COPY that directly opens correctly with a double-click in crazy German Excel 2010. Using ";"-Delimiter is easy. 
The encoding is solved, but Excel only recognizes numbers correctly if they use the  , as decimal seperator.

Thats what the CSV should look like;

```
10,7;8,1;90,0;"some, text."
```

Thats what the CSV looks like now:

```
10.7;8.1;90.0;"some, text."
```

Is there a way to do that with [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-copy.html)?

What I tried:

```
SHOW lc_numeric;
"de_DE.UTF-8"
```

is set but has no effect.

I found [to_char(double precision, text)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-formatting.html) function. But my table has ~200 columns. Will I have to put to_char( column , 'FM9999999999999999D999999999999999999') for every numeric column? Is there any setting to make COPY change it automagically?

Thanks in advance, Steve

Comment: Look at this thread: http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/decimal-seperator-td3328145.html  I'm afraid that you have to find a solution with `to_char`.  I'd expect performing a conversion with Excel may be easier (no actual idea how to do that, just has some faint memories about doing that years ago).